# Random dots excluding certain values or range of values

Tags: random

I am able to generate the random dots, but how would I exclude specific values or range of values? For example, excluding 8 or excluding 10-20.

```
    \begin{pgfpicture} 
      \foreach \x in {1,...,1000}{ 
         \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100} 
         \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{100} 
         \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{+\a pt}{+\b pt}}{+1pt} 
         \color{blue!40!white} \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue!80!black} 
         \pgfusepath{stroke, fill} 
      } 
    \end{pgfpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

The range 10 to 20 can be excluded using `\ifnum` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newif\ifok
\begin{document}
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{blue!40!white}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue!80!black}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,1000}{
      \oktrue
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
      \ifnum\a>9 \ifnum\a<21 \okfalse \fi\fi
      \ifok
        \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{100}
        \ifnum\b>9 \ifnum\b<21 \okfalse\fi\fi
        \ifok
          \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{+\a pt}{+\b pt}}{+1pt}
          \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
        \fi
      \fi
    }
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW, the color settings are constant and are moved outside the loop.

> [image: Result]

The following variant keeps the number of samples constant, but generates only 89 distinct values for `\a` and `\b` and adjusts the output of the random processor to leave the gap of eleven values between 10 and 20:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{blue!40!white}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue!80!black}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,1000}{
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{89}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{89}
      \ifnum\a>9
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\a{\a+11}
      \fi
      \ifnum\b>9
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{\b+11}
      \fi
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{+\a pt}{+\b pt}}{+1pt}
      \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
    }
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powerful `expl3` conditionals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\exclude}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_eightsaregreat_exclude_tl { \c_false_bool }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_eightsaregreat_exclude_tl
     {
      || \int_compare_p:n { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \bool_if:VF \l_eightsaregreat_exclude_tl { #2 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_eightsaregreat_exclude_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_if:nF { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfsetfillcolor{blue!40!white}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue!80!black}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,1000}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{100}
    \exclude{\a=8, 10 <= \a <= 20,\b<5, 30 <= \b <= 50}
      {
       \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{+\a pt}{+\b pt}}{+1pt}
       \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
      }
  }
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

The conditions are concatenated as “or”, with a false condition for keeping the balance, and the code is executed only if the conditions turns out to be false.

[image]